# Is there any significance to fighting zombie sized chickens or chicken sized zombies?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

At the start of the game you are asked whether you would prefer fighting zombie sized chickens or chicken sized zombies.  I noticed that this question is later asked to another character.

Does your answer have any impact in the game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it has any affect on the game but something kinda funny that I noticed in Episode 4 in the segment where you're riding horses to run away from the Wither Storm, while you see some monsters running, if you look closely, you'll notice a chicken sized zombie riding on a chicken.

Comment: Besides, there are baby zombies in Minecraft.

Comment: And you kill it.

Answer (score 1):

*SPOILER WARNING*

> After the credits in Episode 8, the two Old Builders will be either in a land with zombie-sized chickens or chicken-sized zombies depending on which one you picked.

Answer (score 0):

No not really. I mean, are there any chicken sized chickens or zombies sized chickens in the game? Not I don't see any of those in the game. You only fight regular sized zombies and regular sized chickens in the game. Not really much. it's just a stupid question asked from Olivia to Jesse and Lukas.